# new command using math mode sub index bug

Tags: math-mode, macros

I have defined the following command

```
\newcommand{\gsubselector}[2]{$s_{#1,#2}$}
```

and I'm calling it from a document in the following way:

```
... \gsubselector{a,i} : \gsubselector{b,j} there is ...
```

I expect an output such as:

```
... $s_{a,i}$ : $s_{b,j}$ there is ...
```

however, judging from the output pdf that I've got using 'pdfTex', the output corresponds to the following code:

```
... $s_{a,i,:}$ $s_{b,j,t}$ here is ...
```

Am I doing something wrong in the definition?
Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You are only supplying one argument to `\gsubselector`, but have defined it with two. Are you intending to do `\newcommand\gsubselector[1]{$s_{#1}$}\gsubselector{a,i}` or perhaps `\newcommand\gsubselector[2]{$s_{#1,#2}$}\gsubselector{a}{i}`?

Comment: Arguments in LaTeX are not a comma separated list use `{a}{i}`

Answer (score 5):

You just need

```
\newcommand{\gsubselector}[1]{$s_{#1}$}
```

because a call such as

```
\gsubselector{a,i}
```

will make `a,i` as the only argument to `\gsubselector`, so the macro substitution will give

```
$s_{a,i}$
```

as required.

However, I don't think this is a good definition. In your code snippet you type

```
... \gsubselector{a,i} : \gsubselector{b,j} there is ...
```

and this input might result in the colon being at the start of a line, which is quite certainly unwanted.

My impression is that this colon is part of a math formula. I believe it's better to segregate math in its proper environment, so

```
\newcommand{\gsubselector}[1]{s_{#1}}
```

and

```
... $\gsubselector{a,i} : \gsubselector{b,j}$ there is ...
```

so the colon will be properly interpreted as a math relation symbol. There's still a chance that TeX will break a line *after* the colon. If this happens, try adding `\nolinebreak` after the colon

```
... $\gsubselector{a,i} :\nolinebreak \gsubselector{b,j}$ there is ...
```

There are chances that TeX will be able to find a different way of breaking a paragraph; if not, it's a welcome occasion for polishing your prose and reword the text. Good typography requires human help to the machine.

Don't add `\nolinebreak` in every instance: TeX is usually reluctant to break a line after a relation symbol and does it only when the alternative is, at its eyes, worse. But line breaking is not just splitting a long line and stretching or shrinking the interword spacing: semantic considerations are also important and the machine knows nothing about them.

Comment: normally i just need \gsubselector{a,i}. There will be only a few cases where I might need the colon, so the \nolinkebreak will do. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 \newcommand\gsubselector#1{\expandafter\GSUBelector#1!!} 
 \def\GSUBelector#1,#2!!{\ensuremath{s_{#1,#2}}}
```

If it doesn't help create a *complete* example.